# How do I remove a toast notification from Android dex files without decompiling them?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I would like to remove a toast notification from multiple apps. These notifications are displayed every time the app is started and I can clealy see the notification text and code by viewing the dex file with notepad so although I am a noob at this it does not look like I need to decompile the dex file into java source code witch I could not figure out how to do anyways.

http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/3427/code2g.png

Answer (score 1):

Do you own the rights to this app? Then you should have the source code and doing this would be trivial.

If not, don't ask us to help you hack legitimate apps so that you'd save few bucks. Actually, some developers on this site are making a living off of it, so we don't look at this practices fondly.

Just go buy the [Ultima Reversi Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.co.ultimaarchitect.android.reversi.pro&hl=en).

Comment: First off, I don't know how to crack apps and that is not why at all, in fact the apps have already been cracked or are free from the market but are being distributed by someone else who is inserting his name in the apps as if they are his and I know they are not, I just want to undo the changes he is making and you don't have to be a fing douchebag.